# Numba Function Throwing Errors

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to calculate a normalized intraday intensity calculation and use numba in order to speed up the loops.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-70-228319e17353>", line 1, in <module>
    df['price_intensity'] = rh.price_intenstiy(h = df['high'],

  File "C:\Users\Jordan Howell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')

  File "C:\Users\Jordan Howell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 358, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)

  File "C:\Users\Jordan Howell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'scipy.stats._continuous_distns.norm_gen'>
```

I'm not sure if it's `pandas` columns throwing it or what.  I've checked with https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html. I think I'm good with the docs as I convert the pandas series into `numpy` arrays.

I'm not too familiar with numba but here is what I have so far:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit()
def price_intenstiy(h,l,c, o, window=15,smoothing = 2):
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    h = high
    l = low
    c = adjusted close
    o =open
    window = lookback window
    smoothing : parameter for smoothing. usually 2/a-2

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    h = np.array(h)
    l = np.array(l)
    c = np.array(c)
    o = np.array(o)
    
    output = nb.typed.List()
    
    denom = h[0] - l[0]
    
    if denom < 1e-60:
        denom = 1e-60
    else:
        denom = denom
        
    output.append((c[0]-o[0])/denom)
    
    i = 1
    while i < len(h):
        denom = h[i]-l[i]
        high_low = (h[i] - l[i])
        high_previous = (h[i] - c[i-1])
        previous_low = (c[i-1] - l[i])
        term = np.max((high_low, high_previous,
                                previous_low))
        output.append(term)
        
    
    smoothed_output = nb.typed.List()
    alpha = 2/(smoothing+1)
    smoothed = output[0]
    r = 1
    while r < len(output):
        smoothed = alpha*output[r]+(1-alpha)*smoothed
        smoothed_output.append(smoothed)
        
    p = 0
    while p < len(smoothed_output):
        smoothed_output[p] = 100*norm.cdf(.8*np.sqrt(window)*smoothed_output[p])-50
        
    return np.array(smoothed_output)
df['price_intensity'] = rh.price_intenstiy(h = df['high'],
                                           l = df['low'],
                                           c = df['adjusted_close'], 
                                           o = df['open'], 
                                           window=15,
                                           smoothing = 2)
```

Comment: "I think I'm good with the docs as I convert the pandas series into numpy arrays" -- but you are not converting anything into a numpy array (in the code which you have not even shown us beyond the snippet in the error message)

Comment: @talonmies.  The code for the function is after the error message.  Look just below the link to the docs. When I bring in the series as a parameter, I use` np.asarray()` to convert.

Comment: That isn't where the error is happening. It is happening where you **call** the jit function, and there you are passing a panda dataframe slice as an argument to an njit function. That is the error, and that is happening code you haven't shown. It is right there in the error message

Comment: OH! Now I understand what you mean.  I added the code calling the function.  Maybe I could pull the loops out as a separate function then call those functions inside the ultimate function?

Comment: You probably need to use the `to_numpy` function on all those slices you are passing to the njit function to convert them. Remember, the numba compiler has to infer the types of all the arguments at call time